# dynamically use include php into an specific div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a webpage that works with includes (I didin't build it but I'm working on it now), the thing is that the admin page in which I had to make an addition had by default an include into a certain gif which im gonna insert in a picture, that's the whole div that matters , I want to know if there is a way to include the new content I made and include it into that same div so I don't need to reload the whole page.

the piece of code cantaining the default include which isn't commented and the one i wanna add is the one commented

```
  <div id="content-wrapper">
<div class="row" style="opacity: 1;">
<div  class="col-lg-12">

       <div  id="container" class="container" width="100wv" height="100wv">

<?php 
      include 'solicitudlst.phi';
       //include 'pruebaPHP.php';


?>
<script>



</script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>


<?php 
      include 'footer.phi';
?>

      </div>

         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

the commented include is the new one I want to add, and the other one is the one that was by default.

[The blue circle shows the href which is selected by default and contains the content that shows on the right, and the red circle shows the href I wanna click and and change the content on the right by dynamically include the new php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e3vf.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: To do what you're asking look into AJAX.

Comment: as Jay says, ajax is what you need. this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) has a lot of useful info

Comment: Also: smack whoever thought they were being cute by changing the extension. If they say 'for security' smack them again.

Comment: ikr, i mean i dind't build the page but ihave to work with it... and the thing is that i am looking for a way to dynamically change the includes by clicking on dif hrefs , so the includes happens in the same div as they already are but you know after clicking

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
      include ("yourfile.php");
?>
```

That should work.  I'm not really sure what a .phi file is though.

Comment: yeah i am already using the include, the thing is that i need that include to be dynamic which means the content part changes after clicking a href, so the "blank " part of the page is filled with a different include

Comment: Then use a variable for the include file name.

Comment: I have managed to do what I wanted at first but...the ajax i used is only printing the code for the table but not filling anything with actual info, idk what could be wrong there because if I include the other php directly without any functions or ajax into the div i want it shows everything properly but if i use the ajax it just prints the the strcuture butnot content at all